# mysql group by 2 columns combine results

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization

I'm trying to work out how I want to structure this query and am having a bit of difficulty.

Basically, I am trying to get a count of the most used ids in a row where the ids represent objects in another table , except the id can occur in 2 columns.

When I was just dong it for one column, this query worked fine:

```
SELECT rb_1,
       Count(*) AS num
FROM   ci_lineups
GROUP  BY rb_1
ORDER  BY Count(*) DESC
LIMIT  10
```

But now I'll be wanting to do a similar thing, except check a column called `rb_2` as well which can have all the id's `rb_1` will have.

When I try to group by the 2 columns it just considers the groups as combinations of the two columns.

I can write a quick script in PHP to combine and sort the counts if I use my first query twice, once on each column, but I'm thinking there's probably a way to do this with MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT field, sum(cnt)
FROM (
  SELECT rb_1 as field, count(*) as cnt
  FROM ci_lineups
  GROUP BY rb_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rb_2 as field, count(*) as cnt
  FROM ci_lineups
  GROUP BY rb_2
)
GROUP BY field
ORDER BY sum(cnt) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: it throws a "Every derived table must have its own alias" error as written, so I just assigned an arbitrary AS table_name_here after the parentheses part and it works fine.  thanks.